# Generating separate html files from two dataframes for each single row

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframes like below and they always share same first two columns which are unique combination. I want to compose html files for all rows which would contained only one row from two data frames.

| country | number | Particip | EvoParticip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CZ | 2 | 731658.000000000 | 26.100000000 |
| CZ | 4 | 696739.000000000 | -13.200000000 |
| CZ | 5 | 580834.000000000 | -10.500000000 |

and

| country | number | Trans | EvoTrans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CZ | 2 | 1656171.000000000 | 12.900000000 |
| CZ | 4 | 16265.000000000 | 26.000000000 |
| CZ | 5 | 17302.000000000 | 26.200000000 |

Dataframe df0 holds just identifiers:

```
country number  
---------------
0   CZ  2   
1   CZ  4   
2   CZ  5   
3   CZ  7   
4   CZ  10
```

The output html file with the table part should look like this

```
    country number  Particip    EvoParticip 
    CZ  2   731658.000000000    26.100000000
    
    country number  Trans EvoTrans
    CZ  2   1656171.000000000   12.900000000
```

I was able to generate html files with specific naming as need, however the files contains all data from both dataframes. I was not successful in nesting another `for` cycle to do that.

My code is:

```
for i, (r0, r1, r2) in enumerate(zip(df0.to_numpy(), df1.to_numpy(), df2.to_numpy()), 1):
    with open(f"{'_number_'.join(map(str, r0[:2]))}.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as p:
        p.write("<html>\n<head>\n<title>" +"Number: " + f"{'_number_'.join(map(str, r0[1:2]))}" + "</title>\n")
        p.write('<meta charset="utf-8">\n')
        p.write(
            "<style>\nbody{font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}\n"
            + ".textbold{font-weight:bold;}\n"
            + ".divcode{font-family:Courier New,Courier,Lucida Sans Typewriter,Lucida Typewriter,monospace;}\n"
            + ".divpic{padding-bottom: 20pt;}\n"
            + ".textlabel{font-style:italic;font-size:8pt;}\n"
            + "table{border-collapse:collapse;}\n"
            + "</style>\n"
        )
        p.write("</head>\n<body>")

        p.write("<h1>" + "Dashboard" + "</h1>\n")
        p.write('<div class="divpar">\n')
        p.write("<h2>" +"Number: " + f"{'_number_'.join(map(str, r0[1:2]))}" + "</h2>\n")
        p.write("<h2>" + "Month: "+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m") + "</h2>\n")

        p.write(
            ' <div class="divtext"><span class="textbold">Creation date:</span> '
            + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
            + "</div>\n"
        )

        p.write(

            df0.to_html()
            + df1.to_html()
            + df2.to_html()

        )
```

EDIT:

After a bit of struggling I have modified the code so I get every file named as I intended but still I am unable to insert data from dataframe to the html code to display as table. To simplify things I have created one dataframe containing all information and I am extracting the information per row (number) successfully however not in form I would like to. It is now row based info not in table.

For now I have the code like this:

```
for country,number,particip,evoparticip,trans,evotrans in zip(df['country'],df['number'],df['Particip'],df['EvoParticip'],df['Trans'],df['EvoTrans']):
    toWrite = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
    var ID="{country}_{number}";
    document.title = ID;
    </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>\n 
    <h3>Country: {country}  </h3>\n
    <h3>Number: {number}  </h3>\n
    <div class='divtext'>Particip: {particip}</div> 
    <div class='divtext'>Evo Particip: {evoparticip}</div> 
    <div class='divtext'>Trans: {trans}</div> 
    <div class='divtext'>Evo Trans: {evotrans}</div> 
    </body>
    </html>
     """
    
    with open(f'C:/my/path/{country}_{number}.html', "w") as file:
        file.write(toWrite)
```

The output looks like:

[image]

However I dont know how to get the data in table form. Any suggestions?